getCredentialAsync no provider dependencies found - please ensure the desired provider dependencies are added
I tried to run the test app with Firebase and when I click the button Sign in , it prints me error :
getCredentialAsync no provider dependencies found - please ensure the desired provider dependencies are added
I checked Troubleshoot common Credential Manager errors and it says "The androidx.credentials:credentials-play-services-auth: dependency is missing." , but I already added it in dependencies.
    plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.android)
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.gms.google.services)
    alias(libs.plugins.compose.compiler)

}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.firebase_testing"
    compileSdk = 35

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.firebase_testing"
        minSdk = 26
        targetSdk = 35
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.9"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
    implementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.graphics)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling.preview)
    implementation(libs.androidx.material3)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
    androidTestImplementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.junit4)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.manifest)

    implementation(libs.androidx.credentials.v150beta01)
    implementation(libs.androidx.credentials.play.services.auth.v150beta01)
    implementation(libs.googleid)

    implementation(platform(libs.firebase.bom))
    implementation(libs.firebase.auth.ktx)
    implementation(platform(libs.firebase.bom))
    implementation(libs.google.firebase.auth)
    implementation(libs.play.services.auth)
    implementation(platform(libs.firebase.bom.v3370))
    implementation(libs.com.google.firebase.firebase.auth)

}

